# Recommendation on storing 3D flight data in PostgreSQL. Use POINTZM?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgis, postgresql-15

I am looking to store latitude, longitude *(both decimal)* and altitude *(meters)* for use with flight data in PostgreSQL 15.

I have decided on using the `POINT` data type in PostgreSQL for latitude and longitude. I was going to just go with `INTEGER` for altitude but came across the new data type `POINTZM` which allows for storing three-dimensional *(3D)* points with Z and M coordinates.

Which data type is recommended? Using `POINT` and `INTEGER` or using the new `POINTZM`? Mostly just going to be selecting the data out of PostgreSQL with simple selects and graphing on a map via Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you want a `POINTZ`:

```
ST_PointZ(-71.104, 42.315, 3.4, srid => 4326)
```